# TikZ: using the -latex arrow head in decorations.markings

Tags: tikz-pgf, arrows, decorations

Is there a way to get `-latex` arrow heads to work when using `decorations.markings`?

```
\documentclass[convert = false, border = 1cm]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc, arrows, decorations.markings}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[decoration = {markings,
    mark = at position 0.5 with {\arrow{-latex}}
  }
  ]
  \draw[postaction = decorate] (0, 0) circle [radius = 2cm];
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

I have also tried `with {-latex}` but that doesn't work either.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You only need the arrow tip name:

```
\documentclass[convert = false, border = 1cm]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc, arrows, decorations.markings}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[decoration = {markings,
    mark = at position 0.5 with {\arrow{latex}}
  }
  ]
  \draw[postaction = decorate] (0, 0) circle [radius = 2cm];
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Why does it take a just latex and not -latex here?

Comment: @dustin the arrow tip name is just `latex`; the syntax `-latex` means put an arrow tip of type `latex` at the end of the path.