# Add arrowhead to plot

Tags: pgfplots, tikz-arrows

I would like some help to add arrows and text to my plot like this:

[image]

Here is the code that I have so far:

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{datavisualization.formats.functions, arrows.meta}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=newest}

\usetikzlibrary{decorations.pathreplacing,decorations.markings}
%\tikzset{arrow data/.style 2 args={%
%      decoration={%
%         markings,
%         mark=at position #1 with \arrow{#2}},
%         postaction=decorate}
%      }%


\begin{document}


\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[scale=0.9, xmin=0, xmax=30, ymin=-15, ymax=5, grid = both,
axis x line=bottom,thick,axis line style={-Latex[round]},
axis y line=left,thick,axis line style={-Latex[round]},
]

\addplot[red, ultra thick] expression[domain=0:20, samples=100]{1.2*x*(1-(x/15))-(4*x)/(0.5+x)};
\node[below,text=black,font=\Large] at (15,3) {$f(y)$};
\draw[-latex](5,0);
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}


\end{document}
```

[image: screenshot]

Comment: I added the missing semicolon in your MWE code. Please check that your code compiles in the future to not leave that task to someone who wants to answer the question.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can use `marking` with `\usetikzlibrary{decorations.markings}`

- `xticklabels={}`/`yticklabels={}`: removes x,y tick labels
- `axis x line=middle`/`axis y line=middle` or just `axis lines=middle`: axis lines pass the origin
- `every axis y label/.style={
      at={...`: positon axis label
- `postaction={decorate, decoration={markings,
  mark=at position 0.105 with {\arrow{<};},` or `... mark=between positions 0.16 and 0.4 step 0.2 with`: add arrowhead to plot

You can also use the arrow tip `latex` with just using `\arrow{latex}`. The syntax `-latex` means put an arrow tip of type `latex`at the end of the path `-` so `-` is not needed here.  The arrow tip name is just `latex`. So you only need the arrow tip name => `\arrow{latex}`.([Ref. to Gonzalo Medina](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/123522/124842)).

If you want the arrow in reverse direction you can rotate with:

```
\arrow[rotate=-180]{latex};
```

or use the arrow `latex reversed`.

```
\arrow{latex reversed};
```

With this other arrow head or the rotatet arrow style you have to modify positioning maybe a little bit, because of different arrow sizes. Use trial and error to find your positions. Its **not optimal**, its always better with `steps`(see: between position). My strategy is to take care of the total dimension and align for example the first two arrows and then you can add +0.2*x... Dimension here: `2.5`pi -> zero crossing or min/max by 0.2, 0.4, 0.6,0.8, you have to find your own way, if my suggestion is confusing for you.:

```
 mark=at position 0.08 with {\arrow[red,rotate=-180]{latex};},% or latex reversed
 mark=at position 0.28 with {\arrow[red,rotate=-180]{latex};},
 mark=at position 0.52 with {\arrow[blue,rotate=0]{latex};},%0.48 = same direction
 mark=at position 0.72 with {\arrow[blue,rotate=0]{latex};},%0.68 = same direction
 mark=at position 0.88 with {\arrow[blue,rotate=-180]{latex};}
```

Like this?

[image]
 or with `\arrow{latex}` and modified positioning.

[image]

MWE:

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=newest}
\usetikzlibrary{decorations.markings}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[scale=0.9, xmin=-3, xmax=10, ymin=-3, ymax=3, grid = both,
axis x line=middle,thick,xticklabels={},
axis y line=middle,tick style={draw=none},yticklabels={},
xlabel=$y$, ylabel=$\frac{dy}{dt}$,
every axis y label/.style={
    at={(ticklabel* cs:1.00)},
    anchor=west,
},
every axis x label/.style={
    at={(ticklabel* cs:1.00)},
    anchor=west,
}
%,every axis y label/.style={at={(current axis.north west)},xshift=+10pt,rotate=0},
]
%\addplot[red, ultra thick] expression[domain=0:20, samples=100]{1.2*x*(1-(x/15))-(4*x)/(0.5+x)};
\addplot[domain=0:2.5*pi,samples=100,blue,
postaction={decorate, decoration={markings,
%        mark=between positions 0.16 and 0.4 step 0.2 with {\arrow{<};},
%        mark=between positions 0.67 and 0.9 step 0.2 with {\arrow{>};}
mark=at position 0.105 with {\arrow{<};},
mark=at position 0.31 with {\arrow{<};},
mark=at position 0.51 with {\arrow{>};},
mark=at position 0.71 with {\arrow{>};},
 mark=at position 0.9 with {\arrow{<};}
%% Version 2:
 %%mark=at position 0.08 with {\arrow[red,rotate=-180]{latex};},% or latex reversed
 %%mark=at position 0.28 with {\arrow[red,rotate=-180]{latex};},
 %%mark=at position 0.52 with {\arrow[blue,rotate=0]{latex};},
 %%mark=at position 0.72 with {\arrow[blue,rotate=0]{latex};},
 %%mark=at position 0.88 with {\arrow[blue,rotate=-180]{latex};}
%        mark=between positions 0.13 and 0.37 step 0.2 with {\arrow{<};},        mark=between positions 0.43 and 0.77 step 0.16 with {\arrow{>};},
%        mark=at position 0.9 with {\arrow{<};}
      }}
        ]{-sin(deg(x))}node[right,pos=0.9]{$f(y)$};
\node[below,text=black,font=\Large] at (15,3) {$f(y)$};
%\draw[-latex](0,0)--(5,0)node[right]{\emph{Old} latex arrow};
\node[text=red,font=\Large,anchor=north east] at (0,0) {$0$};
\node[text=red,font=\Large,anchor=south east] at (pi,0) {$\theta
$};
\node[text=red,font=\Large,anchor=south west] at (2*pi,0) {$\kappa$};
\draw[black,dotted] (pi,0) -- (pi,-2) node [above left,xshift=0.3em] {\small{extinction}};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Why plot a different function?

Comment: @Torbjørn T. Because of the example image in the question.

Comment: But that cannot be a normal sine function ...

Comment: Nevermind, the concept is the same regardless of function, so I don't think you have to change it, I was mainly curious about why you changed it when the OP provided a function.

Comment: @Bobyandbob, Thanks for your solution.  How do I go about replacing the arrows with the `-latex` scaled arrowhead?  I tried `-latex` but that did not work.  Thanks.

Comment: @Joe .  The syntax `-latex` means put an arrow tip of type `latex `at the end of the path `-`.  The arrow tip name is just `latex`. So you only need the arrow tip name => `\arrow{latex}`. I will edit the answer with this hint.

Comment: @Bobyandbob, Thanks again.  How do I get the arrows to face a specific direction?  I tried `\arrow{>=latex}`, but got an error. Thanks!

Comment: @Joe . You can rotate the tip with `\arrow[rotate=-180]{latex};`.

Comment: Many Thanks!  I sincerely appreciate all your help!

Comment: @Joe I updated the spacing for the rotated arrow. The first tip for aligning(in pdf) are red colored, see 2. image.

Comment: I get the following message when I try to implement the ideas shown here: ! Package pgf Error: I cannot decorate an empty path.

Answer (score 7):

You can add multiple arrows in your decoration, at different positions. This isn't very flexible though, and takes some trial and error to find good positions.

Note that when you do

```
axis x line=bottom,thick,axis line style={-Latex[round]},
axis y line=left,thick,axis line style={-Latex[round]}
```

you repeat yourself needlessly. If the `thick` was meant to make the axis lines thicker, add it to the `axis line style` instead. And you need of course just one `axis line style`.

[image]

```
\documentclass[border=5mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.14} 

\usetikzlibrary{decorations.markings,arrows.meta}
\tikzset{
      myarrowtip/.tip={Straight Barb[length=4pt,width=6pt]},
      arrow data/.style={%
      decoration={%
         markings,
         mark=at position 0.025 with \arrowreversed{myarrowtip},
         mark=at position 0.14 with \arrowreversed{myarrowtip},
         mark=at position 0.28 with \arrow{myarrowtip},
         mark=at position 0.38 with \arrow{myarrowtip},
         mark=at position 0.5 with \arrowreversed{myarrowtip},
         mark=at position 0.7 with \arrowreversed{myarrowtip},
         },
         postaction=decorate}
      }%

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[
 xmin=0, xmax=20, ymin=-15, ymax=5, grid = both,
 axis lines=middle,
 axis line style={-Latex[round],thick},
 yticklabels={},xticklabels={},
 ylabel=$\frac{dy}{dt}$,
 xlabel=$y$,
 clip mode=individual % so that $O$ node isn't clipped away
]

\addplot[arrow data,red, ultra thick] expression[domain=0:20, samples=100]{1.2*x*(1-(x/15))-(4*x)/(0.5+x)} node[pos=0.7,above right,text=black] {$f(y)$};

% x-values found by finding roots of function
\draw [densely dotted] (4.0779,0) -- (4.0779,-15) node[pos=0.7,left,font=\tiny] {extinction};

\node [below left,red] at (0,0) {$O$};
\node [above left,red] at (4.0779,0) {$\theta$};
\node [above right,red] at (10.422,0) {$\kappa$};

\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```