# Pointing out the running sense on the upper semi-ellipse

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots

I want to add a right arrow somewhere at the middle of the upper semi-ellipse `x^2/4+y^2=1`,

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.15}

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}[h]
 \begin{tikzpicture}
        \begin{axis}
                [xlabel=$x$,ylabel=$y$,
                xtick={100},ytick={100},
                no marks,axis equal,axis lines=middle,
                xmin=-2,xmax=2,ymin=-2,ymax=2,
                enlargelimits={upper=0.1}]
             \addplot[color=black, no markers, samples=1001, samples y=0, 
              domain=0:pi, variable=\t] ( {(2*cos(\t r)} , {sin(\t r)} );
            \end{axis}

        \draw (2.98,4.13) node {$1$};
        \draw (2.9,2.38) node {$O$};
        \draw (5.88,2.42) node {$2$};
        \draw (0.3,2.42) node {$-2$};
 \end{tikzpicture}
 \end{figure}

\end{document}
```

by to point out the clockwise running sense:

[image]

How can I do this ?

Comment: You can use the `decorations.markings` library as in for example https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/370875/add-arrowhead-to-plot/370884#370884 Unrelated: Instead of adding the nodes with the ticklabels outside the `axis` environment, place them *inside* the `axis`, then you can place them using the coordinates of the axis, e.g. `\path    node[below left] at (0,0) {$O$}    node[above left] at (0,1) {$1$}  node[below] at (-2,0) {$-2$}    node[below] at (2,0) {$2$};`

Comment: @TorbjørnT. Thank you ! I will try to use your suggestion.

Comment: @TorbjørnT. It works well and it's much easier. Unrelated: how could I decrease the length of the ordinate axis Oy, because of the long "tail" of it under the Ox axis ?

Comment: You have the answer to that in your code already (`ymin`).

Comment: I used xmin=-2.5,xmax=2.5,ymin=0,ymax=1, but there is still a long tail under Ox.

Comment: Ah, right, that's because of `axis equal`, and the default height/width of the axis. Add for example `width=8cm,height=4cm,`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use `decorations.markings` to place an arrow inside the path.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.15}
\usetikzlibrary{decorations.markings}

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}[h]
  \begin{tikzpicture}[
    arrow inside/.style = {
      postaction={decorate},
      decoration={
        markings,
        mark=at position #1,
      }
    }]
    \begin{axis}
      [xlabel=$x$,ylabel=$y$,
      xtick={100},ytick={100},
      no marks,axis equal,axis lines=middle,
      xmin=-2,xmax=2,ymin=-2,ymax=2,
      enlargelimits={upper=0.1}]
      \addplot[color=black, no markers, samples=1001, samples y=0, 
      domain=0:pi, variable=\t,arrow inside=.4 with \arrow{<}] ( {(2*cos(\t r)} , {sin(\t r)} );
    \end{axis}

    \draw (2.98,4.13) node {$1$};
    \draw (2.9,2.38) node {$O$};
    \draw (5.88,2.42) node {$2$};
    \draw (0.3,2.42) node {$-2$};
  \end{tikzpicture}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: @ Henri Menke Thank you for the answer and the full code !