# How to plot a family of rectangular hyperbola streamlines?

Tags: pdftex

I have found code to plot a family of rectangular hyperbola streamlines of the form `x*y = C`. But to extend this code to a family with slanted asymptotes, namely `psi = -0.5*a*xy + 0.25*b*(x^2-y^2)` is too tricky for me.

Comment: Welcome to TEX.SX! Please provide the code you mentioned so that we can help you.

Comment: The code is in:   https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/434557/how-to-plot-this-the-streamlines-xy-c-by-latex