# Add arrowhead to plot: what is missing?

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots, tikz-arrows

In the MWE below, why do not have arrows in my plot?

```
\documentclass[12pt, border=1pc]{standalone}
\RequirePackage{tikz}
\RequirePackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=newest}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta}
\usetikzlibrary{decorations.markings}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[axis x line=middle,
            axis y line=middle,,
            xtick={1.0, 3.0},
            ytick={1.0, 3.0},
            samples=100,
            xmin=-1,xmax=4.5,
            ymin=-1,ymax=4.5]

\addplot[domain={-1:4}]{x};
\addplot[domain={-1:4},
postaction={decorate,
decoration={markings,
    mark=at position 2 with {\arrow[thick]{>}},
    mark=at position 3 with {\arrowreversed[thick]{>}}}
}
]{((x-3)^2 * (x-1)^2) + x};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}  

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: what do you want to accomplish exactly? arrows on both end of the curve?

Comment: Both that (though that part is not mentioned in the question) and at specific point(s).

Comment: Does this answer your question: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/370875/add-arrowhead-to-plot

Comment: Yes I saw it; tried to replicate it, could not do it. So I must be doing something wrong.

Comment: Note that you need to activate/apply the decoration using `decorate`.

Comment: @Jasper Still get the same result.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your range limits on Y combined with your `marks` positions are truncating the arrow.

I debugged it by commenting anything that is not necessary to have arrows to the plot.

```latex
    \begin{tikzpicture}
        \begin{axis}[axis x line=middle,
%           axis y line=middle,
%           xtick={1.0, 3.0},
%           ytick={1.0, 3.0},
%           samples=100,
%           xmin=-1,xmax=4.5,
%           ymin=-1,ymax=4.5,
            ]
            
%           \addplot[domain={-1:4}]{x};
            \addplot[domain={-1:4},
            postaction={decorate, decoration={
                markings,
                mark=at position 0.65 with {\arrow{>};}
            }}
            ]{((x-3)^2 * (x-1)^2) + x};
        \end{axis}
    \end{tikzpicture}
```

[image]

The arrow is exactly where I thought it would be 65% of the plotted curve.

By playing a bit with the code:

```latex
    \begin{tikzpicture}
        \begin{axis}[
%           axis x line=middle,
%           axis y line=middle,
%           xtick={1, 3.0},
%           ytick={1.0, 3.0},
            samples=100,
            xmin=-1,xmax=4,
            ymin=-1,ymax=4.5,
            ]                   
%           \addplot[domain={-1:4}]{x};
            \addplot[domain={-1:4.5},
            postaction={decorate, decoration={
                markings,
                mark=at position 0.65 with {\arrow{>};}
            }}
            ]{((x-3)^2 * (x-1)^2) + x};
        \end{axis}
    \end{tikzpicture}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you. I do not understand this truncating business. In my example, for example, I npow did .85 and it worked, I see the arrow. I did .7, .75, .9, and I see no arrow. I am confused.

Comment: My understanding is that the `addplot` command is executed before the `axis`environment limits the plot. So the curve is plotted. Then the arrow is positioned at x%. Then x or y limit truncates it.

Comment: Thank you. Is there an alternative approach?

Comment: https://tikz.dev/pgfplots/reference-specifyrange#autosec-5859. 
Check this option: `update limits=true|false (initially true)`.

Comment: or changing the plotting tool to https://tikz.dev/dv-introduction